# Why do I only receive a single alert from the following javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a javascript function inside of a HTML  tag, however - when I move the alert(currentalbum) below the for loop, the second alert does not run - only the first, why?

```
function populatetracks(albumvalue) {
    var currentalbum = albumvalue;
    alert(currentalbum); // #1

    document.getElementById("TracksList").options.length = 0; 

    for(i = 0; albums[albumvalue].tracks.length - 1; i++) {
        var s = document.getElementById('TracksList');
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.appendChild( document.createTextNode(albums[albumvalue].tracks[i].title));
        opt.value = i;
        s.appendChild(opt);
    }

    alert(currentalbum); // #2
}
```

'#1' does produce an alert, but '#2' doesn't.

Comment: At a glance, it looks like the `for` loop never finishes.

Comment: @Quentin Unless the track list has length 1 exactly, in which case the "condition" evaluates to `0`, a falsy value, and skips the loop entirely.

Comment: try `i < albums[albumvalue].tracks.length - 1`

Comment: there is no assignment operator in the for loop condition

Comment: It should do, after the i=0 - I define the i value to where the for loop should stop.

Comment: Just realised i'd left that out, thank you again - might have solved many more problems than just that.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, not sure how your for loop is supposed to stop.

This has no evaluation in it, just an incrementor

```
for(i=0; albums[albumvalue].tracks.length -1; i++){
```

Maybe try this (might need to change  '='  to  '<='  )

```
for(i=0; i < albums[albumvalue].tracks.length -1; i++){
```